# Is it possible to convert dynamic framework to static library in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to convert dynamic framework to static library?

The problem is that I don't have a source code of framework, but only `SomeFramework.framework` file which is dynamic library for few architectures

Comment: Is the framework made in Swift ?

Comment: Haven't tried this myself but worth trying - https://github.com/pkrmf/dynamic-to-static

Comment: @Nitish I already tried that, but it require source code and xcodeproj file :-(

Comment: Found anything?

Comment: @Emixam23 no luck :-(

Answer (score 2):

Create a "**Cocoa Touch Framework**" and add your .framework to the "**Linked frameworks and Libraries**" then you can:

- Go to *Build Settings > Match-O Type > choose what you want...*

or

- you can also add a "static library" as new target of your dynamic framework.

Don't forget to add the [modulemap / Umbrella](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002253-97623-BAJJHAJC) to expose what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Request you some more info about where and how to add the modulemap/umbrella?

Comment: Thanks! adding a static lib as a new target to the existing framework saved me a lot of manual work.