# Can we generate an objective-c static library from a swift framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios, static-libraries, swift-framework

I have a xamarin project in which I need to integrate a native iOS code. To be precise a framework written in swift. Since xamarin officially doesn't support binding swift frameworks, Is there any possible way to convert this swift framework into Objective-C static library?

Comment: Sone have had success. Have you tried this https://xamarin-ios.programmingpedia.net/en/tutorial/6091/binding-swift-libraries

Comment: This is integrating a swift framework into xamarin. I would like to know if there are any way to convert a swift framework into a static library for which there is official support is available and moreover we can avoid adding all those swift nugets.

Comment: Convert - no. You can write objective-c wrapping library of swift's framework and use it in xamarin.

Comment: @Cy-4AH could you elaborate on the same. Links to some documentations or some helpful guides would be much appricated.

Answer (score 0):

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788485/is-it-possible-to-convert-dynamic-framework-to-static-library-in-xcode) ways of converting a Swift framework to an Obj-C static library.

Also, there doesn't seem to be any "official support" available.