# App using xcframework CocoaPod logs classes implemented in both app and framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods, xcframework

We have created a CocoaPod which is an XCFramework that has dependencies on other CocoaPods. When we run the demo example app or install the pod in a new app, it works, however this is logged to the console on launch (repeated for many classes):

> objc[38875]: Class OTSubscriber is implemented in both
> /Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8DD81910-DD40-4BD7-9355-8A0C78EFD32E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/60E8C18A-37DC-4C2B-AEB3-E88C3A7C4D96/MyCocoaPod_Example.app/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
> (0x10e3fd660) and
> /Users/MyUser/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8DD81910-DD40-4BD7-9355-8A0C78EFD32E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/60E8C18A-37DC-4C2B-AEB3-E88C3A7C4D96/MyCocoaPod_Example.app/MyCocoaPod_Example
> (0x10c8abd80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.

This class is from OpenTok, which is a dependency specified for the pod used in the framework. The message seems to reveal CocoaPods is installing the dependencies on the app in addition to the framework, causing this issue. The app itself shouldn't have any dependencies except this framework.

Perhaps something was done incorrectly in the pod creation process? These are the steps we took:

- Create an Xcode framework project, add a Podfile listing its dependencies, build out the framework's functionality
- Create an XCFramework from the framework's xcworkspace
- Create the pod using `pod lib create MyCocoaPod` choosing iOS, Swift, include demo, none and no for testing
- Update the Podspec:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'MyCocoaPod'
  s.version          = '1.0.0'
  s.summary          = 'Summary'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
'Description'
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'https://myhomepage.com'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Author' => 'auther@somedomain.com' }

  s.ios.deployment_target = '12.0'

  s.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/user/git-repo.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'MyFramework.xcframework'
  s.swift_version = '5.5.2'

  s.dependency 'OpenTok', '2.21.3'

  # Needed to pass lint validation
  s.pod_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
  s.user_target_xcconfig = { 'EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]' => 'arm64' }
end
```

- Drag and drop MyFramework.xcframework into Pods/Development Pods/MyCocoPod
- Update the example's Podfile to specify `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION = YES`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```

- Run `pod install` in Example directory - note this will cause the framework to be moved to the root level in Finder and under a Frameworks group in Xcode
- Update the example app's code to import and use MyFramework
- Commit, tag, and push the changes to the repo
- Push the Podspec to the specs repo

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is your case but maybe you are falling in a scenario which happened to me,
meaning a dynamic framework that depends on a static framework. In such scenario, your dynamic framework would end up embedding the static one in his resulting binary. Then, in order to import your dynamic framework in the project, you will import with the setting “Embed and sign” for example, as that’s indeed a dynamic one, along with the other static framework which your dynamic one depends on. This causes the duplicated implementation ( your app including the static dependency + the dynamic one embedding inside the same dependency.

What you could do if this is your case, is to make sure that the dynamic framework configuration is changed to be static (static xcframework to be precise) , maybe outside cocoa pod as first step if that simplifies. Code wise would be the same, but it will “link” to the dependency (OpenTok for example) rather than embedding it. As result, once imported in the app, it should be imported only once, as your custom framework links to it and does not embeds it, finally avoiding the duplicated implementation. (static  frameworks are imported with “Do not embed” which means that they will be merged in compile time to the app executable)

Comment: We do indeed have a static framework included in our framework, ACRCloud. This seemingly wouldn't cause the duplicate implementation though because the classes it's logging are not in ACRCloud, the one noted is from OpenTok which is added as a dependency in the Podspec unlike ACRCloud which is directly in the framework source.

Comment: How would we change the framework configuration to be static rather than dynamic to try that out?

Comment: I quickly googled and here the first result found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48788485/is-it-possible-to-convert-dynamic-framework-to-static-library-in-xcode although I suggest to create a new project, and from the list pick the static library (the knwon .a files just to clarify). You should be able to blindly copy the files from your current dynamic framework project and put in this new one for static lib. To make a static framework out if it, you just need to compile the lib for simulator and for arm device, picking the respective “.a” file and craft the xcframework folder structure

Comment: Eventually, here is how to make a static framework starting from static libs: https://medium.com/onfido-tech/distributing-compiled-ios-swift-static-libraries-and-swift-static-frameworks-7fecc4f3d182